# Apache Camel Type Converter List

Tags: apache-camel

Apache Camel has over 300+ type converters available for use out of the box. As a developer, I can add more type converters as well. But is there any way where I can find the full list of Camel Type converters available out of the box? I searched in Camel source in GitHub, however could not get a list. This would help me in taking a decision whether I should provide an implementation or I can use the one already available in Camel.

I know many components can add Type Converters when we add them to class path. I just wanted to know the ones already available with Camel core (or the most useful ones).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A way to list what's available out of the box would be to grep the content of each `META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverterLoader` that you can find on the github repo but I think it would be nice to have some of them listed on the website.

Do you mind opening an issue ?

Comment: Thanks, will do!

Comment: Done - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15582. Thanks